# [ERROR:engineio.server:Invalid session]. Why can't I access my flask app more than once?

Tags: apache, flask, flask-socketio, flask-session

I am running a Flask app on Ubuntu with Apache, using flask_socket_io. It works just fine the first time round, but if I try to access the website again or from a different device, that error shows up in the error.log.

Any help is very much appreciated!

I tried using flask_session, but the problem persists.